# Get immediate subdirectory of a root directory containing a subdirectory

Tags: ant

I have a following directory structure

- root_dir

  - fixed_dir
  - random_dir

    - subdir1
    - subdir2

      - subdir2.1
    - subdir3

      - subdir3.1
      - subdir3.2

In the ANT build file I know the `root_dir`, `fixed_dir`, and one directory that is either `random_dir` or a subdirectory below `random_dir` (`subdirX`). I need to determine the path of `random_dir` given some `subdirX`. Is it possible to find this directory in ANT and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tested solution for finding the immediate subdirectory of a root directory that contains some subdirectory `subdirX` at any level of nesting given the file structure provided in the question.

```
<property name="root.dir" location="${basedir}/root_dir" />
<property name="subdirX" value="subdir2.1" />

<target name="find-immediate-subdir-of-root-containing-subdirX">
  <dirset dir="${root.dir}" includes="**/${subdirX}" id="mydirset" />
  <pathconvert property="random_dir" pathsep="${line.separator}" refid="mydirset">
    <mapper type="regexp"
        from="^(${root.dir}${file.separator}[^${file.separator}]+).*"
        to="\1"/>
  </pathconvert>
  <echo message="${random_dir}" />
</target>
```

### Output

```
find-immediate-subdir-of-root-containing-subdirX:
     [echo] /ant/project/basedir/root_dir/random_dir

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how deep in subdirectory structure subdir is. I don't know a way in ANT to recursively go "up" the directory structure.

Comment: @JanneKulin: Are you attempting to accomplish the following? `while (subdir.parent != root_dir) { subdir = subdir.parent } return subdir`

Comment: Thank you, this helped to find the correct solution. This did not work directly, as my subdir property was full path, but based on some assumptions I could find out the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

With [Ant addon Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) you'll get the parent as property of a file object (see [Flaka Manual](http://workbench.haefelinger.it/flaka/download/manual/flaka-1.2.2.html), section 3.7.2, i.e.

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

<!-- let standard ant tasks, i.e. echo
     understand EL expresssions -->
<fl:install-property-handler />

<echo>#{file('${basedir}').parent}</echo>

<!-- or without fl:install-property-handler use fl:echo-->
<fl:echo>#{file('${basedir}').parent}</fl:echo>

</project>
```

so you would use :

```
#{file('${yoursubdir}').parent
```

Comment: Same problem as with the previous answer about not finding the direct parent directory, but some upper level directory that is direct child of the one known directory.

Flaka seems to offer a lot of possibilities, so using that it might be possible to achieve what I'm wanting to do, but needs some more studying. Preferable I would not use addons, but I might not have possibility to avoid that.

Comment: "..about not finding the direct parent directory.." but the parent function gives you the direct parent directory of a given fileobject - a directory in your case !?also possible

Comment: "..about not finding the direct parent directory.." but the parent function gives you the direct parent directory of a given fileobject - a directory in your case !? also possible #{file('${somedir').parent.parent.parent...}  Also there are several ways to iterate over a dirset, but we need to know what you're looking for ;-) so redefine your search criteria or give more details and we are able to help you

Comment: cpeisert wrote it clearly: while (subdir.parent != root_dir) { subdir = subdir.parent } return subdir. This is what I'm looking for. Direct child of root_dir in same path as subdir.